# not able to install dask on google colab

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory, dask

I use pip method to install on google lab. But I am not sure why it is not working.
Here is what I got
code

```
pip install "dask[dataframe]" --upgrade
```

error

```
Requirement already up-to-date: dask[dataframe] in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2021.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: partd>=0.3.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dask[dataframe]) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cloudpickle>=1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dask[dataframe]) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: toolz>=0.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dask[dataframe]) (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: fsspec>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dask[dataframe]) (0.8.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dask[dataframe]) (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.16; extra == "dataframe" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dask[dataframe]) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pandas>=0.25.0; extra == "dataframe" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dask[dataframe]) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: locket in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from partd>=0.3.10->dask[dataframe]) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fsspec>=0.6.0->dask[dataframe]) (3.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.25.0; extra == "dataframe"->dask[dataframe]) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.25.0; extra == "dataframe"->dask[dataframe]) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->fsspec>=0.6.0->dask[dataframe]) (3.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: typing-extensions>=3.6.4; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->fsspec>=0.6.0->dask[dataframe]) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=0.25.0; extra == "dataframe"->dask[dataframe]) (1.15.0)
```

If I take the dataframe to use. Notification like this happens
code

```
 import dask.dataframe as dd
```

error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py in <module>()
     34     from .optimize import optimize
---> 35     from .multi import merge, concat, merge_asof
     36     from . import rolling, backends

3 frames
ImportError: cannot import name 'keys_in_tasks' from 'dask.core' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/core.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py in <module>()
     55         '  python -m pip install "dask[dataframe]" --upgrade  # or python -m pip install'
     56     )
---> 57     raise ImportError(msg) from e

ImportError: Dask dataframe requirements are not installed.

Please either conda or pip install as follows:

  conda install dask                     # either conda install
  python -m pip install "dask[dataframe]" --upgrade  # or python -m pip install

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

I am using google colab to writing, why it is not available here? how could I fix it?

Comment: If I run `!pip install "dask[dataframe]"` in a Colab notebook and then `import dask.dataframe as dd`, I don't get any errors.

Comment: @AlexK I still got the same problem. Is this something caused by colab?

Comment: Maybe, there was this Github issue with a recommended solution that might help you: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6301

Comment: @AlexK, Thanks, but I already tried that. It is not working either. I just solved by copy every code into a new colab file. It works. But not sure next time I open this will work or not

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
!python -m pip install "dask[complete]"
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to restart runtime after installing before importing.